# how to call javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ruby

```
var img = '<textarea cols="60" id=' + div_id + ' name=handle[' + required_name + '] rows="7">';
img = img + '<div id="fullscreen-button-'+id+'" style="position:relative;left:220px;width:24px;height:24px;cursor:pointer;background-image:url(../assets/resize_full.png);" onclick="fullscreen('+'"'+path+'"'+')"></div>';
img = img + '<embed src=' + path + ' width="" height="" />';
img = img + '</textarea>';
```

============================================

**Output coming is**

```
<div id="fullscreen-button-0" style="position:relative;left:220px;width:24px;height:24px;cursor:pointer;background-image:url(../assets/resize_full.png);" onclick="fullscreen(" upload microsite micro_1 calcsmall.swf')'></div>

onclick="fullscreen(" upload microsite micro_1 calcsmall.swf')'
```

**I want**

**`onclick="fullscreen('upload/microsite/micro_1/calcsmall.swf')"`**

Comment: can you paste what does path variable contain anyway perhap then we can help

Comment: path = upload/microsite/micro_1/calcsmall.swf

Comment: actually I'm using all this in javascript code. No use of rails.

Comment: @manish_nautiyal why not render like this `%Q{<div id="fullscreen-button-'#{id}'" style="position:relative;left:220px;width:24px;height:24px;cursor:pointer;background-image:url(../assets/resize_full.png);" onclick="fullscreen('#{path}')"></div>}`

Comment: @Viren when I click on a image I change the value of text-area and then save it on table. And on another page I display it. I'm using handle_bar for this. So I have to use javascript.

Comment: my mistake btw what wron with your code check over here `http://jsfiddle.net/meetme2meat/vPpDs/`

Answer (score 1):

```
img = img + '<div id="fullscreen-button-'+id+'" style="position:relative;left:220px;width:24px;height:24px;cursor:pointer;background-image:url(../assets/resize_full.png);" onclick="fullscreen(\''+path+'\')"></div>';
```